# Does an Eclipse CVS merge appear in the log view of a file?

Tags: eclipse, merge, cvs, branch

I'm not new to the Branch/Merge idea, but I'm new to CVS.  I have a sample file that I have brached off of the main trunk, and have made non-conflicting edits to both the branch and the main.

When I go to Merge, however, the process leaves me with all of my changes in a file representing the latest revision of the Main trunk.  When I commit this file, the "log" for the file in SmartCVS shows me that the changes have been committed, but it doesn't signify that the branch has been brought back into the Main trunk.

Will I actually see this in the log view, or is the notion of a merge something that has to be represented in tags or check-in comments?

Thanks!
IVR Avenger

Answer (score 0):

CVS does not track merges automatically. In order to do this you will have to adopt your own comment and/or tagging scheme.

In my experience we made sure everyone who merged added comments to indicate where the merge had come from. It was labourious.